# ASP.NET web page with crystal report viewer is not loading on client system

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, master-pages

**ASP.NET page inside master page having crystal report viewer object**, not even loading on client system. Crystal report runtime is installed on client system.

> Here is my error page Image
>   *General_Responsive is master page Name*[image]

Comment: this looks like a server error. Can you confirm if the missing assembly App_Web_xp2.... is referenced in your aspx project

Comment: I was transferring app data over AnyDesk, Might be some data lost while transferring. I zip my published App and zip it and send it over mail and download on client system from mail. This way my problems fixed.